# What is 'unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5 returned from attempted TeXLive update

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to update all the packages in my TeXLive install on Ubuntu Focal. When I run
`tlmgr update --all`, I get following error message:

> unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

I'm using version 5.0.3 installed from the Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `-5` means that signature verification for a repository has failed. There is currently a bug in `tlmgr` that prevents a sensible error message from being printed, but this is being worked on and should be fixed soon.

Above is quoted from answers on TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange [Answer 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/528635). Please read [a second answer too](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/537810). Thanks to Henri Menke and Alessandro Cuttin.